# Why am I geting this error? AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'periodogram'

Tags: python, scipy

I have copied the following lines

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fs = 10e3
N = 1e5
amp = 2*np.sqrt(2)
freq = 1234.0
noise_power = 0.001 * fs / 2
time = np.arange(N) / fs
x = amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*time)
x += np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(noise_power), size=time.shape)
# Compute and plot the power spectral density.

f, Pxx_den = signal.periodogram(x, fs)
plt.semilogy(f, Pxx_den)
plt.xlabel('frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('PSD [V**2/Hz]')
plt.show()
```

from **http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.periodogram.html#scipy.signal.periodogram  but when I try to run the code I'm getting this error:

```
f, Pxx_den = signal.periodogram(x, fs)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'periodogram'
```

I'm using Scipy version 0.12
Thank your for your help.
Kind Regards.
Ivo

Comment: in an interpreter type `from scipy import signal` and then type `dir(signal)` and do you see 'periodogram' in that list?

Comment: What do you get if you `print signal`?

Comment: When I print dir(signal) I get a lot of methods but not the periodogram. If i change  from scipy import signal to from scipy.signal import spectral I will get the lombscargle method. Was this method removed from scipy v0.12? Or is in another module? Kind Regards.Ivo

Comment: the API states that its supposed to be there in .12..... so you may have had some sort of installation problem. ive never used scipy, so im not sure if its installed like a traditional python module, but maybe check site-packages/scipy/signal ?

Comment: yea, definately an installation problem. my dir(signal) definately has periodogram in it ( i just installed it )

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will reinstall it and check if everything is working ok. Kind Regards. Ivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>>from scipy import signal

>>>print [x for x in dir(signal) if x == 'periodogram'] #just list comprehension to limit the amount of methods displayed
['periodogram']
```

You definitely have something wrong with your installation of scipy. I recommend [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy) this site in general is usually my first place to go when having difficulty installing or importing modules that you believe to be installed correctly.

The list of stuff on the website is not 100% of everything, but most of the big important stuff you can find there.