# too many indicies for an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, wav, spectrogram

I've used the code from user Anil_M in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284049/spectrogram-of-a-wave-file/43347984#43347984) i want to get the same result. but in My case it plots the first image [image]

and after that i get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Maram/Desktop/Spectrogram/first_attempt.py", line 73, in <module>
    fftArray = fftArray[0:numUniquePoints]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

and i dont get this 
[image]

or when i try to use a slightly larger wav file, it doesnt even display the first image. I just get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:/Users/Maram/Desktop/Spectrogram/first_attempt.py", line 38, in <module>
        mySoundOneChannel = mySound[:,0]
    IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I think these errors are somehow related but i just don't understand how or why it's caused.

could someone help me get it to run say a larger wav file/longer track, or help me get my existing code to run the power against frequency graph? 
any help would be really appreciated.

(I dont know if this is considered a duplicate - in the original question no one has the same problems im facing.)

Comment: In the first what is `numUniquePoints`?  In the second, what is `mySound.shape`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `mySoundOneChannel = mySound[:,0]` reads the first channel of the file. If your file contains only 1 channel change it to `mySoundOneChannel = mySound[0:]`

As for the second issue - `numUniquePoints` is of type `float`, so you must cast it - `numUniquePoints = int(numpy.ceil((mySoundLength + 1) / 2.0))`.