# Speech analysis using Python) How do I view the result of the analysis of the speech file in time on the x-axis and decibels on the y-axis?

Tags: python

I have a question while running the code written in this link([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284049/spectrogram-of-a-wave-file/43347984#43347984), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064682/too-many-indicies-for-an-array)).

In this code, the results were shown in Hertz on the x-axis and decibels on the y-axis. How do I view this graph in decibels on the x-axis and time on the y-axis?

(This question is a bit awkward because I used a translator.)

Comment: I don't think you want to use this code; it uses the fast fourier transform which converts a signal from one domain (such as time) into another (such as frequency) so it wouldn't be trivial to just change the view of the graph. What is it you need decibels over time for?

Comment: Sorry, I used the opposite value.

I want to get a graph where the x-axis is time and the y-axis is decibels.

I want to know the change in decibels over time by analyzing the voice.

Comment: I know but that doesn't change the point that I made

Comment: I want to know the size of the decibel over time because I need to know the time to know where the decibel is high in the audio file.

Comment: I would suggest looking into downloading Praat and extracting the amplitude value over time, it would be much easier data to work with in python

Comment: Thank you for your advice very much!I'll try it right now